# Can I place all ssl directives in NGINX's http block?

Tags: nginx

I've a webserver serving several subdomains (the usual nginx.conf with a sites-enabled folder), and I'm updating ssl_ciphers, ssl_dhparam, etc.

Given that I want the same security measures for all the subdomains, can I place ssl_ciphers, ssl_dhparam, ssl_protocols, etc. in the http block of nginx.conf, rather than repeating in every subdomain's server block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Yes

In [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html) each directive specifies a *context* which are the blocks within which the directives may be placed. All of the `ssl_` directives can be placed in the `http` or `server` contexts.

Comment: No idea how I missed the context bit!  Thanks very much.